# How to make my options go to the very right of my question?

Tags: html, css

So far, I have determined that to keep my options (the rectangles with color) to the very right, I have to have my text fill up a whole line if not more.

In my form, the different topic questions are separated into tables as shown in the code below. For some of the tables, the options go to the very right since the questions take up the whole line, but for other tables, the questions are too short so the options don't reach the far right.

To address the problem, I have tried to put in filler white space or even text whose visibility is none, but everytime, for the options to be to the very right (as I want it to be), the text has to go onto the next line.

```css
td:first-child {
   width:85%;
}

input[type=radio]{
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
}

.yesImage, .noImage {
    background-color:navajowhite;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + .yesImage {
    background-color:black;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + .noImage {
    background-color:black;
}

.optionImage {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    height:35px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in;
}

.yesImage, .noImage {
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p class="questions" id="question1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="question1" id="yes1" value="yes"><label class="yesImage optionImage" for="yes1">
                            </label>
                            <input type="radio" name="question1" id="no1" value="no"><label class="noImage optionImage" for="no1">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td> 
                            <p class="questions" id="question2"> Lorem ipsum. (Question 2) </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="question2" id="yes2" value="yes"><label class="yesImage optionImage" for="yes2">
                            </label>
                            <input type="radio" name="question2" id="no2" value="no"><label class="noImage optionImage" for="no2">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p class="questions" id="question3"> Lorem ipsum. (Question 3) </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="question3" id="yes3" value="yes"><label class="yesImage optionImage" for="yes3">
                                </label>
                                <input type="radio" name="question3" id="no3" value="no"><label class="noImage optionImage" for="no3">
                                </label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p class="questions" id="question4"> Lorem ipsum. (Question 4) </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="question4" id="yes4" value="yes"><label class="yesImage optionImage" for="yes4">
                                </label>
                                <input type="radio" name="question4" id="no4" value="no"><label class="noImage optionImage" for="no4">
                                </label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>

            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p class="questions" id="question5"> Lorem ipsum. (Question 5)<span id="whitespace"> filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text</span> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="question5" id="yes5" value="yes" class="skippedQuestions"><label class="yesImage optionImage" for="yes5">
                            </label>
                            <input type="radio" name="question5" id="no5" value="no" class="skippedQuestions"><label class="noImage optionImage" for="no5">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p class="questions" id="question4"> Lorem ipsum. (Question 6) </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="question6" id="yes6" value="yes" class="skippedQuestions"><label class="yesImage optionImage" for="yes6">
                            </label>
                            <input type="radio" name="question6" id="no6" value="no" class="skippedQuestions"><label class="noImage optionImage" for="no6">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
           </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Please keep in mind this is an example of my problem.]

Please go full page when using the snippet so my problem can be seen more easily.

This is what I want (without the extra lines between the questions):
[image]

Comment: Problem #1: You're using tables for layout

Comment: You can use tables for layout but there are better ways.  How about you show us a picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @j08691 I'm using tables to keep the questions and the answers aligned together. The problem I'm facing is that different tables are facing different alignments unless at least 1 question per table takes up more than a full line. I have a table, however, with questions that are only one line, so the answers are aligned separately from the other tables. Do you know how I can fix that problem?

Comment: Tables should be used for tabular data, not aligning anything. That's what CSS is for. Look into flexbox or CSS grids

Comment: @DCR I'll work on that. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @j08691 I will look into that. I used tables because I found that to be a solution on another stackoverflow question, but if there are better ways, I'll be sure to look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution of your problem. I added some properties in my css in the solution and marked these by comments. Hope it will help you.

```css
table { /*Add this block in your css*/
   width: 100%; /*Newly Added*/
}

td:first-child {
   width:85%;
}

td:nth-child(2) { /*Newly Added*/
   width:15%; /*Newly Added*/
}

input[type=radio]{
   -webkit-appearance:none;
   -moz-appearance:none;
   appearance:none;
   display: none; /*Newly Added*/
}
 
.yesImage, .noImage {
   width: 30% !important; /*Newly Added*/
   margin-right: 5%; /*Newly Added*/
   background-color:navajowhite;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + .yesImage {
    background-color:black;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + .noImage {
    background-color:black;
}

.optionImage {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    height:35px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in;
}

.yesImage, .noImage {
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p class="questions" id="question1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="question1" id="yes1" value="yes"><label class="yesImage optionImage" for="yes1">
                            </label>
                            <input type="radio" name="question1" id="no1" value="no"><label class="noImage optionImage" for="no1">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td> 
                            <p class="questions" id="question2"> Lorem ipsum. (Question 2) </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="question2" id="yes2" value="yes"><label class="yesImage optionImage" for="yes2">
                            </label>
                            <input type="radio" name="question2" id="no2" value="no"><label class="noImage optionImage" for="no2">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p class="questions" id="question3"> Lorem ipsum. (Question 3) </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="question3" id="yes3" value="yes"><label class="yesImage optionImage" for="yes3">
                                </label>
                                <input type="radio" name="question3" id="no3" value="no"><label class="noImage optionImage" for="no3">
                                </label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p class="questions" id="question4"> Lorem ipsum. (Question 4) </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="question4" id="yes4" value="yes"><label class="yesImage optionImage" for="yes4">
                                </label>
                                <input type="radio" name="question4" id="no4" value="no"><label class="noImage optionImage" for="no4">
                                </label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>

            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p class="questions" id="question5"> Lorem ipsum. (Question 5)<span id="whitespace"> filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text</span> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="question5" id="yes5" value="yes" class="skippedQuestions"><label class="yesImage optionImage" for="yes5">
                            </label>
                            <input type="radio" name="question5" id="no5" value="no" class="skippedQuestions"><label class="noImage optionImage" for="no5">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p class="questions" id="question4"> Lorem ipsum. (Question 6) </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="question6" id="yes6" value="yes" class="skippedQuestions"><label class="yesImage optionImage" for="yes6">
                            </label>
                            <input type="radio" name="question6" id="no6" value="no" class="skippedQuestions"><label class="noImage optionImage" for="no6">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
           </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just try above make the tales with width 100%.

```
table{
 width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: if you only use table {width: 100%}, the code will not work properly for the small screen size. @Prasad Gayan